# Is some setting responsible for unresponsiveness of CVC entering

Tags: keyboard, samsung-note-20, cvc

For the last few weeks, I have been unable to enter the CVC for the credit card on the phone.

- Whether its an app going to a service called **Windcave** or a site in the browser going to it, I can fill in everything, but the CVC.
- I don't know if this for all services for credit card, or just limited to Windcave, because every app/site I use so far is going through it.
- I have looked at the Samsung keyboard settings, nothing jumps out.  I havent changed anything for months anyway.
- If I madly, repeatedly press the digits of the keyboard, they get entered.
- If I madly press the same digit, it does not get entered, unless I am hitting it at two different spots.
- I have no problems doing anything else on the phone.  The keyboard behaves perfectly.
- Since Chrome is my default browser, I assume the Windcave site is running on Chrome.